# RMI Security Manager

Tags: java, rmi

I'm currently planning a presentation about RMI and found that the
"RMISecurityManager" is deprecated.
But when I search for a different way to apply a policy file i can't find one.
So I'm asking for a way to do this, or if it's even needed anymore.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: You don't need it unless you're planning to use the codebase feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/RMISecurityManager.html) :

> RMI applications should use the SecurityManager class or another appropriate SecurityManager implementation instead of this class

Anyway, the RMISecurityManager class was just an empty shell.

Comment: Ah thank you, I just didn't thought that another Security Manager would do the Job exactly the same way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Back in 1.1 `RMISecurityManager` really was different. It used a `URL` where today we would `AccessControlContext`.